# Spin up new EC2 instances programatically with Python Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

What I'm trying to do, is not have to manually create new EC2 instances as needed through the AWS.Amazon.com site, but rather programtically start up new instances based off a ami using python's boto module

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-2",
    aws_access_key_id='<aws access key>',
    aws_secret_access_key='<aws secret key>')

#how to now spin up new instances based off a snapshot (already) preconfigured on ec2?
```

As in my comment, I'm trying to startup new instances based off a specific given ami id?

I can't seem to find a good way to do this. Can anyone help here?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ec2_tut.html):

> Possibly, the most important and common task you’ll use EC2 for is to
>   launch, stop and terminate instances. In its most primitive form, you
>   can launch an instance as follows:
>
> ```
> conn.run_instances('<ami-image-id>')
> ```
>
> This will launch an instance in the specified region with the default parameters. You will not be
>   able to SSH into this machine, as it doesn’t have a security group
>   set. See EC2 Security Groups for details on creating one.
>
> Now, let’s say that you already have a key pair, want a specific type
>   of instance, and you have your security group all setup. In this case
>   we can use the keyword arguments to accomplish that:
>
> ```
> conn.run_instances(
>     '<ami-image-id>',
>     key_name='myKey',
>     instance_type='c1.xlarge',
>     security_groups=['your-security-group-here'])
> ```

The `<ami-image-id>` is where you fill in your ami id.

Comment: So, I could effectively run this multiple times and run multiple instances of a single AMI id?

Comment: yes, you can even create multiple instances in a single call (after all, it is called run_instances...)